# How can I see Type.InvokeMember method implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to see `InvokeMember` method implementation of `Type` class.But when I right click to the method and click `Go To Declaration`, all I'm seeing is an **abstract** method definition like this:

```
abstract public Object InvokeMember( /* parameters */ );
```

And there are two overloaded version of this method, but they are calling this abstract version:

```
[DebuggerStepThroughAttribute]
[Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden] 
 public Object InvokeMember(String name,BindingFlags invokeAttr,Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
 {
      return InvokeMember(name,invokeAttr,binder,target,args,null,culture,null);
 } 

 [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute] 
 [Diagnostics.DebuggerHidden] 
 public Object InvokeMember(String name,BindingFlags invokeAttr,Binder binder, Object target, Object[] args)
 { 
      return InvokeMember(name,invokeAttr,binder,target,args,null,null,null);
 }
```

I can see all implementations of other methods and classes.But I can't see `InvokeMember` implementation, why ? Where is that implementation ?

Note: *I'm using `.NET Reflector` and `ReSharper`*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are overrides of `InvokeMember` abstract method:

[image]

So you will be probably interested in `System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember` which is an internal, concrete class derived from `System.Type`.

Comment: thanks, it was really simple, how I couldn't see that ? :-) I will accept your answer in five minutes :)